# SQL Join the count to a query

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, count, group-by, distinct

I have created a database of my movies and another with my actors in each movie

Columns are:

- ID
- Actor
- ImdbActorID
- ImdbMovieID
- Character

Example:

47105 | Howard McGillin | nm0569294 | tt0111333 | Adult Prince Derek 
47106 | Michelle Nicastro | nm0629264 | tt0111333 | Adult Princess Odette 
47108 | John Cleese | nm0000092 | tt0111333 | Jean-Bob

when my webapp queries a specific movie:
**Select * from actors where ImdbMovieID='tt0111333'**

I get that list. What my problem is I would like to add a column of the total movies I have of each actor. so i don't programatically have to run a query for each actor

I've thought of joining the same table to itself with the count??? but I don't know if that will even work. what stumps me is having that where clause.

Comment: The query doesn't really make sense. You have a column in `Actors` called `ImdbMovieID`? If an actor has been in two movies, what is in that column? Is this a relation table, where each actor/movie combination is listed together? If so, that's not a very intuitive name for the table.

Comment: You have a typo in your SELECT statement in the comments; the table is named ActorS, not Actor (which is why you get that error).  However, as @AaronBertrand pointed out, it's not intuitively named :(

Comment: I apologize there was a pic of my table but my rep is low so i couldn't post it. I tried a query:
i tried the query thinking i would be a bit closer: 
Select ImdbActorID,cnt from Actors Join (Select ImdbActorID as Act2, count(*) as cnt from Actors group by ImdbActorID) as x on Actor.ImdbActorID=x.Act2 where ImdbMovieID='tt0111333' 

and i get the error: The multi-part identifier "Actor.ImdbActorID" could not be bound.

Comment: Thanks everyone Stuart and Aaron.

Select ImdbActorID, Character,Actor,ImdbMovieID,cnt from Actors 
Join (Select ImdbActorID as Act2, count(*) as cnt from Actors group by ImdbActorID) as x on Actors.ImdbActorID=x.Act2 

where ImdbMovieID='tt0111333' order by cnt desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone Stuart and Aaron.

Select ImdbActorID, Character,Actor,ImdbMovieID,cnt from Actors

**Join (Select ImdbActorID as Act2, count(*) as cnt 
        from Actors group by ImdbActorID) as x on Actors.ImdbActorID=x.Act2**
where ImdbMovieID='tt0111333'

order by cnt desc